# json returned from asmx method can't be parsed in Javascript

Tags: .net, jquery, asmx

I am trying to return a json object of array of arrays like this one:

```
{
     'data': [[45,43,103],[34,43,230]]
}
```

using asmx in .NET 4.0 like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public string GetData() {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("'Data':[");
sb.Append("[45,43,103],");
sb.Append("[34,43,230]");
sb.Append("]");
return sb.ToString();
```

using jQuery ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,  //defined elsewhere
    data: "{}",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: update,  

  });
```

and

```
function update(data)
{
 console.log (data.d[1][1]); //looking at second array second element
}
```

**The problem is the response from the asmx call looks like this and my update function doesn't work**

```
{"d":"\u0027Data\u0027:[[45,43,50],[34,43,50]]"}
```

Things don't look like they are escaped or formatted properly. It seems I am missing something. Why does 'data' still have the unicode chars for '? I thought ResponseFormat.Json would take care of everything to put it in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't return a json containing array of arrays. You return a string (`'Data':[[45,43,50],[34,43,50]]`) encapsulated in a json.

2 things are wrong with your approach.

**a)** don't form a json manually using string operations

**b)** return a real object in your method instead of string

So Changing your method to something like below should work

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<int[]> GetData()
{
    return new List<int[]>() { new[] { 45, 43, 103 }, new[] { 34, 43, 230 } };
}
```